# How to move a file to a random location in python (traceable)

Tags: python

I'm trying to be able to move a files from a folder containing lots of files to different, but random places.
I am trying to find a way to keep track of where was each file moved, or make it replicable in any case.
This is my code to move files to random destinations, but how can keep control of where did each file go? Would setting a random seed be the solution?
Code:

```
import os
import random
import shutil
location = ['Documents','Desktop','Downloads','Music','Pictures','Videos']
for files in os.listdir('C:\\Users\\name.lastname\\Documents\\lots_of_files'):
    shutil.move('C:\\Users\\name.lastname\\Documents\\lots_of_files\\'+files, 'C:\\Users\\name.lastname\\'+location[random.randint(0,len(location))])
```

*This is a legitimate question and should not be adressed subjectively please.*
A few hours ago I was working with a folder with 80000 json files and doing lots of operations with its data and I got a memory error. So I created 10 folders with 8000 files each and managed to solve the problem in chunks of 8000 files per folder. I moved this files in an ascending order, but if I wanted to move them randomly to any of the 10 folders I created then this would be a solution.

Comment: What's your use case for this? I'm trying to think of a legitimate reason one would want to do this.

Comment: @EdCottrell To ruin someone else's life.

Comment: @d_kennetz It seems well-suited to that task.

Comment: A friend and I are learning and playing python-based practical jokes, and for the sake of fairness, I am trying to be able to keep track of where each file has gone so it's easier to recover it. I already tried this in my computer and with the code I shared they did go to random places, but I want to be able to keep traceabality to ensure there is no harm done. Also, ruin someone else's life is a bit far-fetched if you ask me.

Comment: I just found a reason. Matter of fact it has an explination. A few hours ago I was working with a folder with 80000 json files and doing lots of operations with its data and I got a memory error. So I created 10 folders with 8000 files each and managed to solve the problem in chunks of 8000 files per folder. I moved this files in an ascending order, but if I wanted to move them randomly to any of the 10 folders I created then this would be solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why you'd ever want to do this.

But...

```
import os
import random
import shutil
import numpy as np
from collections import defaultdict

root_dir = 'C:\\Users\\name.lastname\\'
locations = ['Documents','Desktop','Downloads','Music','Pictures','Videos']
cwd = os.getcwd()

files = os.listdir(cwd)
file_history = defaultdict(list)
file_history.update({file: cwd for file in files})  # Mark all files as having been in the CWD first

for file in files:
    new_path = os.path.join(root_dir, np.random.choice(locations))

    file_history[file] += new_path

    shutil.move(os.path.join(cwd, file),
                os.path.join(new_path, file))
```

This should store the movement for each file in `file_history` which is a dictionary keyed by each files name. If you want to preserve this, then be sure to save it to file before the script terminates.

Also, I don't know if this is bug-free because I'm not going to run this on my machine.

Comment: Thanks I'll try it on my pc, I don't mind. I don't know why people downvoted my question. I feel they are being unfair towards my question, I'm not asking for something to ***harm*** somebody. I'll let you know if it's bug free :)

Comment: Hah! This moved files from another directory, an important one in fact! But it ***did*** print out the destinations, so whatever... I'll move them back 1 by 1 now. Well played.